# Continuous earning on the bases of one time hard work

Tags: halal-haram

Assalam u`Alaikum,

Continuous earning from a source which was built by only one time hard work.
Is it Halal or Haram or something else...?

For Example, A person creates a Website / App.

- If the website sell some product or services, then What is the Rule.?
- If website does not sell anything, the earning is only from Advertisements on the website/app, then what is the Rule...?

I want to ask that, If this money Halal or Haram...?

Thanks.

Comment: Depends on the contents, even the contents of advertisement as your App is hosting such ads, and as long as continuous earnings are on halal basis(not involving haram trade as smoke or alcohol ......etc) and paying Zakat then all is good!

Comment: When we are doing no effort to Earn, we just Sit and Eat... Is it Halal or Jaaezz...?

Comment: Hmmm, that i'm not quite sure about sorry, but you might want to include your comment in your question summary therefore it's clear for others who may have an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has part of the answer in it.

Let's suppose you have some money, and you construct a house and put it on rent. Now it will continue to generate income. You only invested your time and money once and enjoying the continuous income. I agree that there would be some maintenance involved but that is not equal to the initial investment (unless the house has to be reconstructed).

Now let's suppose you write a book (an [intellectual property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intellectual_property)). You worked hard and got the book in market. People found that book interesting and millions of copies are sold.

On the same lines, you created a software (again an [intellectual property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intellectual_property)). You and your team worked hard for months or years and the software took off. As in the house example, there will definitely be maintenance involved but not as much as the initial investment.

So in all these examples, initial investment of time and money are huge. It is not like selling merchandise.

Here is a [Fatwa](http://www.beautifulislam.net/halalharam/copyright.htm) by [Mufti Taqi Usmani](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_Taqi_Usmani).